# Image rendering not working with TextureLoader in three.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, three.js

Following is my method for adding an image using three.js -

```
rendererModule.addImage = function (primitive){
    var self = this;
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    console.log("HERE 1");
    textureLoader.load("image/myimage.jpg", function(map){
        console.log("HERE 2");
        map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        var mat = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map:map, color:0xFFFFFF, fog:true});
        var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(mat);
        sprite.name = primitive.id;
        self.setProperties(sprite,primitive);
        sprite.position.z = -15;
        var distance = camera.position.distanceTo(sprite.position);
        var halfHeight = distance * Math.atan( camera.fov/2 * Math.PI / 180 );
        sprite.scale.x = halfHeight * 2;
        sprite.scale.y = halfHeight * 2;
        scene.add(sprite);
        self.renderView();
    });
    console.log("HERE 3");
}
```

and I am using the method like this -

```
workitems.forEach(function(item, index, array){
    if(item['type'] === "planar-item" ) {
        vedit.renderer.addPlane(item);
    } else if(item['type']==="image-item"){
            vedit.renderer.addImage(item);     
    }
});
```

Though my plane method is working fine but not the image one.....another surprise is that `"HERE 1"` & `"HERE 3"` is printing in the console, but not 2. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The second question has the easier answer: `function(map) {...}` is a callback for an asynchronous operation, so inline code before and after it is guaranteed to run first (the Javascript engine won't pick up async operations until after the current context finishes) and it's not necessarily the case that it will run at all. Since it's an "onload" in this case, it won't run if the resource is never loaded. You probably want to put an onError callback in there to see what's going on.

As for the first, I can't reliably answer that without an error message, but the most likely cause of course is just that the file doesn't exist (at that path). An easy way to test is to just create an `<img src="image/myimage.jpg"/>`, programatically or hard-coded, and see if it appears.

Comment: thx for the response .... btw I dont think its related to path as I tried by adding a url like `http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nature-q-c-150-150-8.jpg` and its was not working...how can I change the behavior of my function to track the things going on under `textureLoader.load`

Comment: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader

You can add the fourth argument (onError function) like in the example on the page, and at least put a breakpoint on it to see what the state is.

Answer (score 0):

In according to other answer the problem is most likely the opening failure of the image; you can easly check in your browser developer tool in the network section.

The main causes of this issue can be:

- Wrong path, if your image path is http://yoursite/imahe/myimage.jpg try to add slash in your load parameter

  textureLoader.load("/image/myimage.jpg", ...
- Privilege error, you have to check the privilege, the owner of the file and permission (644 can be fine)

Other problems can be caused bywrong virtualhost, .htaccess or other webserver configuration, but is hard to say what...

Notice that if you try lo load image from other domain (like http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nature-q-c-150-150-8.jpg) you have a cross-domain error and the load fail!